# Can I set some validation to be a default setting on a TextBox instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

In my program I have lots of Textboxes.

They are all bound via MVVM-Pattern.

Everything works nice. Now I want to implent some kind of Validation and have decided to use a mix of Validationrules AND! IDataErrorInfo.
After testing this out a few times it all works well.
But now I have a question.

I write my XAML-Code like

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Width="150" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Lets say I have 40 TextBoxes in total. Do I always have to write

```
Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
```

or can I set this to be some sort of default?

I do not want to create a derived TextBox because of three properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Textbox.Text binds TwoWay by default, so no need to specify it here. For the other thing, the only idea that comes to my mind is to create a CustomBinding.

```
    public class MyBinding : Binding
{
    public MyBinding()
        :base()
    {
        this.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        this.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        this.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
        this.UpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }

    public MyBinding(string path) 
        : base(path)
    {
        this.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        this.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        this.ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
        this.UpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    }
}


<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <local:MyBinding Path="Value" />
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I think thats an acceptable solution because its very compact and reusable